# Automatically press a specific keyboard key in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, scripting

Is there a way to get MATLAB to automatically press a specific keyboard key?
My internet connection disconnects without no reason. I want to make a script in MATLAB which check the internet connection status periodically and if the connection is disconnected the program will run the connection automatically.
I want to write a script in MATLAB which automatically run a connection (first picture). Then program should automatically press Enter key (“Connect” button in the first picture).  After this the second window will appear(second picture). In the second window if I click “connect” button, then the connection will connect to the internet. 
Here is my script:

```
function [] = AutoConn()
tic ;

cTime = 2 ;
k = 0 ;
A = 0 ;
while(1)
    nTime = toc ;
    tic ;
    C = isnett ;
    if C == 1
        A = 1 ;
    else
        A = 0 ;
        system('C:\...\Connection.pbk');
      {....}

    end
    clc;
    k = k+1;
    k
    A
    pause(cTime) ;
end


function flag = isnett()
% This function returns a 1 if basic internet connectivity
% is present and returns a zero if no internet connectivity
% is detected.

% define the URL for US Naval Observatory Time page
url =java.net.URL('http://tycho.usno.navy.mil/cgi-bin/timer.pl');

% read the URL
try
    link = openStream(url);
    parse = java.io.InputStreamReader(link);
    snip = java.io.BufferedReader(parse);
catch
    flag = 0;
    return
end
if ~isempty(snip)
    flag = 1;
else
    flag = 0;
end
```

First Picture:
               https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEy6W.png

Second Picture:
               https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPlEN.png

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think that Matlab can't do it. you could use autohotkey to do it (google it).

Comment: What happens when the "enter" key is pressed? Why don't you bypass the enter key entirely, and run whatever function it calls? What creates this dialog in the first place? Is there any other user interaction with the dialog before "matlab hits enter"? I can't understand what triggers the "and now Matlab presses the key" - somehow, whatever that is should be able to "do whatever happens after the key is pressed", and bypass the dialog entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, although undocumented, Matlab can do that by using java.awt.Robot, [see Undocumented Matlab post on this topic](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/gui-automation-robot/).

It mentions a very nice FEX that facilitates the job for you: [inputEmu](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28603-inputEmu).

Using [inputEmu](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28603-inputEmu) all you need to do is:

```
inputemu('key_normal','\ENTER');
```

**Note:** You will need to test if AWT is available:

```
error(javachk('awt'))
```

or

```
if usejava('awt')
   myFrame = java.awt.Frame;
else
   disp('Unable to open a Java Frame.');
end
```